Subtracting list values from previous list values
If I have a list of values like this:
a=[5,4,3,2,1]

How would I then go about subtracting a value from the one before it and storing it in a new list?  In this example, the new list would look like:
b=[1,1,1,1]

I'm assuming this could be done with a for loop, but I'm not sure how to index the values.  The data I will be working with has hundreds of entries, so is there a way to reference a previous entry in a list?

This is possible by storing the difference between two neighboring elements in a variable and then adding it to your array. You can then use [i-1] to reference the previous element:
a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = []
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    dif = a[i-1] - a[i]
    b.append(dif)


We could use Python's list comprehension to accomplish this, pal. We can assign the result of the list comprehension to b. Take a look at the code example below:
a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = [a[i - 1] - a[i] for i in range(1, len(a))]
print(b)

Happy coding, bud!

Not sure that you need abs. OP never mentions that.

Yeah, it is not really needed, I just thought of handling negatives, but they should be added as they come, not being changed, hence, we don't need the abs fn in reality. Thanks!

Just iterate through the list elements.
a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = []

for i in range (0, len(a) - 1):
    b.append(a[i] - a[i + 1])

You can also start from 1 going to len(a) and use a[i - 1] - a[i] for finding the subtraction.
for i in range (1, len(a)):
    b.append(a[i - 1] - a[i])

